# How to TDD the creation of a Random Integer Range in Scala using Regex?

Tags: regex, scala, tdd

The aim is to TDD a Random Integer Range from 1 until 10 in Scala using Regex.

**Test**

```
test("randomInteger") {
  assert(NumberSequences.randomInteger(10) === 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10)
}
```

**Main**

```
def randomInteger(a: Int) : Int = {
  scala.util.Random.nextInt(a) + 1 
}
```

**Outcome**

```
> test
[error] 
numbersequences\scala\NumberSequencesTest.scala:53: 
value | is not a member of Option[String]
[error]     assert(NumberSequences.randomInteger(10) === 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10)
[error]                                                   ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Jul 29, 2014 8:25:28 PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a regex? This makes your test slow and difficult to read. You can just `assert` the value to be within a specific range:

```
val randomNumber = NumberSequences.randomInteger(10)
assert(randomNumber > 0 && randomNumber < 11)
```

Having that said, from a TDD point of view I wouldn't use the real randomn number generator at all. I'd inject a mock to take the place of `scala.util.Random` so that its `nextInt()` function provides the same fixed number every time. This way I wouldn't have to account for the random nature of the real function and could focus on testing the functionality of my own implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm ... in my opinion your approach is a bit off. One of the best TDD tips I've ever received was: 'Don't test the framework.' I'm guessing that scala.util.Random.nextInt(a) is a function that is generally available to Scala users. From a TDD point of view you can generally assume it works.

What you can TDD is the transformation of your array. You transform the array by adding 1 to each of the ints in order to shift the 0-9 range up to 1-10. You can write a test and a matching function where the function's job is to add 1 to each int in an array. In your case you can then pass in result of scala.util.Random.nextInt(a) into the function. I know that this seems trivial, but thinking in this way has made TDD accessible to me and it has improved my coding tremendously.

Just to complete the example, if you were actually writing the code for the scala.util.Random.nextInt() function then you could TDD it. Basically you would set the pseudo-random seed to a certain value, generate the next pseudo-random number and then verify that the new number is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex


val digits = """[1-9]|10""".r
assert(digits.pattern.matcher("0").matches())
```